# panel-body textarea disappear after jquery filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, summernote

I show info in a section of collapse panels, the content are showed in `<textarea>` elements inside of the `panel-body` but the text that is showed are stored in `HTML` so I use `Summernote` to show it, that Works fine but when I make a search if that search match with the `panel-header` content the panel doesn't shows the textarea/summernote element.

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h0j1Lmcm/) if you search for `one` makes the filter and shows you the right panel but when try to expand the panel the textarea/summernote element is not there. But if you search for `lorem` shows you the panel and can be expanded.

**How can I solve this? is because the use of summernote or the jquery script I use to make the search?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is easy to figure out when you inspect the live html. The summernote plugin also uses a `panel` class so when you hide `panel` it gets hidden too.

A quick workaround is use:

```
 $('.panel').not('.note-editor')
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h0j1Lmcm/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: This Works awesome, so another point I just check is that the filter starts after the second letter and only happen when I use summernote, so I gess I have to check the live HTML to figure why, thank you so much =D.

Comment: depends what you type... keep in mind you are checking every bit of text in the panel

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `<textarea>` to `<div>` and it works.

Is there any restriction to just use `<textarea>` ?

If so, let me know then I can try to come up with a real solution.

Or you can just get away with this one without wasting time :)

Comment: Right. 
@charlietfl you got it bang on !